# Do I require permissions to run SPServices on Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2010, spservices

I require assistance with Sharepoint. I've tried multiple ways to retrieve data from a list and have had little to no success, after much reading and searching I'm still no further ahead.

I am using a list made by another user, which I can add,edit and delete items from. When calling this list using SPServices I seem to hitting a wall. Here is my third attempt at trying to access the list and now I have received a `404` response and `responsetext` is null.

The URL is correct, cause it actually loads the list of values.

If i have an empty webURL parameter, the parameter of `responsetext` has a helpful SOAP response stating the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring><detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    List does not exist.
    The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
    </errorstring><errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000006</errorcode></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Here is my call which when I define the webURL to point to the list, it always returns a http 404 with `responseText=null` no matter what the url is. This is not very helpful. The Url I am pointing to loads the list.

```
function getListItems_RFC(){
   var url = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() + 
                "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/RFCExtract";
   console.log("getListItems_RFC() "+ url);
   $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            webURL: url,
            async: false,
            listName: "RFC Extract",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
            completefunc: 
               function (xData, Status) {
                  console.log(Status); //outputs error
                  console.log(xData); //outputs array responseText:null and status:404
                       $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("m:properties").each(function() {
                      var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("d:Title") + "</li>";
                      $("#debug").append(liHtml);
                  });
               } 
       });
};
```

I have modified the url each possible way:

```
var url = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() + 
                    "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/"; //responseText=null, status:404
var url = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite();//responseText=null, status:404
var url = "" //responseText=soapresponse above, status:500
```

Why is this not working??? What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your implemetation to something other ?
Your way is very complicated by my opinion. Third party libraries here are unnecessary.
Good way is to use out-of-box REST API or JSOM. It is easy to use.

I see you want to get list item Title field.
Use REST API this way:
http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Title

Here you can find example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-rest-api

May be you can use for SharePoint 2010:

```
var myRestApiUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/RFCExtract?$select=Title";
var get = function (url) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
};
get(myRestApiUrl)
.then(function(response){
    // TODO: do actions with response

});
```

Comment: I believe the url you're providing is for a different version of SharePoint, it reutnrs a http 404. I have tried this multiple ways. I was successful but not in this one. Just looking for a potential fix. I actually was successful using REST API. :)

Comment: Please can you open in browser url: https://<site url>/sites/<Web>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc. Here you can find all list names. May be your list name has different name without whitespaces or something else. I don't have SP 2010 by hand but I think it must be not very different from SP 2013. I created list "RFC Extract" and url "_vti_bin/ListData.svc/RFCExtract" return me correct data in browser.

Comment: I not believe that it is not working. If you can open target link in browser then problem in SPServices call settings. Try to build url with all parameters in browser. When it will be working then wrap it in js. This API must work very well. By my opinion

Comment: Yes that last URL you mentioned matches the one I am using. I have been successful in using REST API but this question is regarding SPServices. I am more curious to learn more about this for I was successful in using REST API. :)

Comment: You can debug SPServices call in browser and see real URL which called and why it is not working. Just to watch on Google Chrome Network tab. Can you write target URL (removing confident data) that exists there. Is it same as working for you in browser manually ?

Comment: Can you use plain jquery ajax call ? Like $.ajax ? Like here: https://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/22/list-items-manipulation-via-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2010/ . ? And use /_vti_bin/ListData.svc/RFCExtract?$select=Title url.

Comment: I updated answer, try to use code for SP 2010 from it. It uses jquery, not SPServices. Is it not working?

Comment: I upvoted that comment, that's the solution I have implemented. I got that working. This has been solved using REST API.  Thank you.

Comment: If it works, please don't forget to accept answer as the best answer.